# Postgresql dblink_exec not working with $$

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run following query

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS dblink;

DO 
$$

declare database_name TEXT;
declare conn_template TEXT;
declare conn_string TEXT;
declare query_string TEXT;
BEGIN
    conn_template = 'user=postgres_user password=postgres_password dbname=';
    query_string = 'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION datadog.explain_statement(
                    l_query TEXT,
                    OUT explain JSON
                    )
                    RETURNS SETOF JSON AS
                    $$
                    DECLARE
                    curs REFCURSOR;
                    plan JSON;
                    BEGIN
                    OPEN curs FOR EXECUTE pg_catalog.concat(''EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON) '', l_query);
                    FETCH curs INTO plan;
                    CLOSE curs;
                    RETURN QUERY SELECT plan;
                    END;
                    $$
                    LANGUAGE ''plpgsql''
                    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
                    SECURITY DEFINER;';

    FOR database_name IN
        SELECT datname FROM pg_database
        WHERE datistemplate = false
    LOOP
        conn_string = conn_template || database_name;
        perform dblink_exec(conn_string, format(query_string));  
    END LOOP;

END
$$
```

It works with a single db, but not working for all. returning following error

```
Error occurred during SQL query execution

Reason:
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "DECLARE"
  Position: 461
```

How to run this for all database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$ nested within $$, so the second $$ closes the first one, rather than stacking up a new open. Choose a different delimiter for (at least) one of the pair, like $DO$ for the outer pair. That is most of the point of dollar quoting, after all--you get to choose what the "quote mark" is so it doesn't interfere with other ones.